# How stream stdout from subprocess.Popen to file?

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, popen, kill

How create live stream stdout from subprocess.Popen to file
I need it because after killing subprocess all stdout deleted but i want to keep stdout after killing

Start script file:

```
result = subprocess.Popen([f'{parameters}', f'{url_script}'], stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stdout, bufsize=0)
r.set(id_, result.pid)

result.wait()
```

Killing process:

```
 `process_id = r.get(id_)
 os.kill(int(process_id), signal.SIGTERM)`
```

Comment: Please show us the code you have written so far.

Comment: what do you mean by stdout deleted it after killing?

Answer (score 0):

```
out = subprocess.run("test.exe",stdout=subprocess.PIPE, timeout=5, shell=True)
data= str(outStd.stdout.decode().strip())
```

If you store the stdout in variable suppose it will be there until you terminate your script or variable being modify.